# Is it possible to save an HTML file locally and then open it locally but still keep the original src and hrefs

Tags: html, webserver, localhost, relative-path

If I find a webpage I want to tinker with and I save the source to the desktop, change a couple of bits, and then re-open - then often all the `src` and `href`attributes don't work as they are relative to the original hosting folder eg `/Images/picture1.jpg` or `/Scripts/script1.js`.

Is there a way to 'trick' the browser into persisting these relative references? Preferably without going through every one of them and appending a path to the front - which I have also tried but without success. What is the format of the fully qualified path name for these resources?

Let me know if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)

Comment: Click the link. It has examples.

Comment: Thanks - followed your link :)